# Getting text from an external command line app, every time there is a new line, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are lots of questions on S.E about executing a single command,  such as listing a directory, and getting its output. This is not one of those.

I want to monitor an Interactive Fiction interpreter (which I can launch form Python), and get each command the player enters, plus any response to it, then process hits, rinse & repeat.

So, the play might type "take gold" and interpreter reply "you now have a massive gold ingot. Be careful not to drop it on your foot". After which, the player issues a new command and gets a new response.

Where my question differs is that the player could be playing for hours, and I don't want to wait until the end to get entire transcript. I want it in real time.

I don't think that I can do that with `subprocess`, but maybe I missed something?

The only other idea I have is to [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) the program and capture its output that way, but that requires bundling a `tee` porgram with my Python script if I distribute it.

Any suggestions?